# Height and level order of tree Node

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, tree

Please have a look at the code and let me know where is an issue. As I want to find height and level order but the output is nothing. As the left and right node always contains null values.

Here is main function:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        
       Tree t1 = new Tree();
       Tree t2 = new Tree();
       t1.makeTree();
       t1.levelOrder(); //0 1 2 3 4 5 6 13 14 15 7 8 9 10 11 12
       System.out.println("height: " + t1.height()); //3
       t2.makeTree2();
       t2.levelOrder(); //0 1 2 3
       System.out.println("height: " + t2.height()); //1
       System.out.println("sub tree t1 and t1 " + t1.isSubTree(t1));
       System.out.println("sub tree t1 and t2 " + t1.isSubTree(t2)); //t2 is not a subTree of t1
       Tree t3 = new Tree();
       t3.makeTree3();
       t3.levelOrder();
       System.out.println("sub tree t1 and t3 " + t1.isSubTree(t3)); //t3 is a subTree of t1
       Tree t4 = new Tree();
       t4.makeTree4();
       t4.levelOrder();
       System.out.println("sub tree t1 and t4 " + t1.isSubTree(t4)); //t4 is a subTree of t1
 
     }
 }
```

Here is tree class:

```
class Tree{   
   private static class TNode{
       private int value;
       private TNode parent;
       private TNode left, right;
       private List<TNode> children;
       
       public TNode(){
          this(0, null);
       }
       public TNode(int e){
          this(e, null);
       }
       public TNode(int e, TNode p){
          value = e;
          parent = p;
          left=right=null;
          children = new ArrayList<TNode>();
       }    
   }

   private TNode root;    
   private int size;    

   Tree(){
     root = null;
     size = 0; 
   }

   public TNode createNode(int e, TNode p){
        return new TNode(e, p);
   }

   public TNode addChild(TNode n, int e){
        TNode temp = createNode(e, n);
        n.children.add(temp);
        size++;
        return temp;
   }

   public void makeTree(){
        root = createNode(0, null);
        size++;
        buildTree(root, 3);
   }

   public void makeTree2(){
        root = createNode(0, null); 
        size++; 
        buildTree(root, 1);
   }

   public void makeTree3(){
        root = createNode(3, null); 
        size++; 
   }

   public void makeTree4(){
        root = createNode(2, null); 
        size += 13; 
        buildTree(root, 1);
        size -= 12;
   }

   private void buildTree(TNode n, int i){
        if (i <= 0) return;
        TNode fc = addChild(n, size);
        TNode sc = addChild(n, size);
        TNode tc = addChild(n, size);
        buildTree(fc, i - 1);
        buildTree(sc, i - 2);
        if (i % 2 == 0)
           buildTree(tc, i - 1);    
   } 

   public long height(TNode n){
       /*implement*/
       if (n == null)
            return 0;
         else
         {
             /* compute  height of each subtree */
             long lheight = height(n.left);
             long rheight = height(n.right);
              
             /* use the larger one */
             if (lheight > rheight)
                 return(lheight+1);
             else return(rheight+1);
         }
     // return 0;    }    public long height(){
       return height(root);    
   } 

   public void levelOrder(){
       /*implement*/
        Queue<TNode> queue = new LinkedList<TNode>();
         queue.add(root);
         while (!queue.isEmpty())
         {
  
             
             TNode tempNode = queue.poll();
             //System.out.print(tempNode.value + " ");
  
             /*Enqueue left child */
             if (tempNode.left != null) {
                 queue.add(tempNode.left);
             }
  
             /*Enqueue right child */
             if (tempNode.right != null) {
                 queue.add(tempNode.right);
             }
         }    }    public boolean isSubTree(Tree st){
       /*implement for extra credit*/ return false;    
   } 
}
```

Comment: Your main problems are code formatting and that `addChild` operates on `children`, whereas `height` and `levelOrder` operate on `left` and `right`. Choose either a binary tree (`left`/`right`) or an arbitrary tree (`children`).

Comment: Will you please guide me how i can find the height and level of arbitrary tree? I searched alot but all in vain

Comment: You already got good advice above. What have you done with it? You are populating `children`, not `left` and `right`, so when you have an algorithm that traverses via `left` and `right` it is normal that you get nothing.

Comment: Actually i want to find the height and level order of this tree. But i don't know how to do this? I need suggestion to do this

Comment: It starts by taking advice into consideration. It is a major flaw in your code which you should address first. It explains the problem that you described in your first paragraph. If you were able to write the code that you presented, then surely you can change it to remove the reference to `children` and replace it with appropriate use of `left` and `right`. Or is this code not yours?

Comment: Its partially mine, as i edited the code, my task was to find the height and level order. I implemented both functions with BST. and they are fine. Then i used same function in this code but no result. Then i debug the code and got that null values. I have got this point. As this code whole size is 16 and childern list are taking 3. But i am stuck at a point who can i traverse with children.

Comment: I cannot change the other code, i can only change both functions height and level order. Its requirement. It will be kind help if you guide me how to traverse with children array

Comment: It seems you are ignoring what has been said above. Why does your class define `left`, `right` and `children`? What is the purpose? Please explain their significance. Also only one of the two functions you mention uses a BST traversal.

Comment: My class was not defining left , right. I added them for the implementation of height. Original class have only following data members.                                                               
      private int value;
      private TNode parent;
       private List<TNode> children;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [this extra bit of information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66855331/height-and-level-order-of-tree-node#comment118182640_66855331), the question is now answerable:

> Original class have only following data members: `private int value; private TNode parent; private List<TNode> children;`

So you're trying to implement `height()` and `levelOrder()` for an arbitrary tree. You already know how to implement these functions for a binary tree. What we need to do is adapt the algorithms you know for the data structure you have.

Let's start with the left/right version that you have:

```
public long height(TNode n){
  if (n == null) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    /* compute height of each subtree */
    long lheight = height(n.left);
    long rheight = height(n.right);
    
    /* use the larger one */
    if (lheight > rheight) {
      return(lheight+1);
    } else {
      return(rheight+1);
    }
  }
  return 0; 
}
```

This is correct. All that needs to happen is to change it from recursing on left and right to using the contents of children. The algorithm is the same, as the comments indicate:

```
public long height(TNode n){
  if (n == null) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    /* compute height of each subtree */
    
    /* use the larger one */

  }
  return 0;    
}
```

How can we compute the height of each subtree?

```
for (TNode child : n.children) {
  /* compute height of each subtree */
  long childHeight = height(child);
}
```

But we need to keep track of the largest one.

```
long highest = 0;
for (TNode child : n.children) {

  /* compute height of each subtree */
  long childHeight = height(child);

  /* use the larger one */
  highest = Math.max(highest, childHeight);
}
return highest + 1;
```

Putting it all together:

```
public long height(TNode n){
  if (n == null) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    long highest = 0;
    for (TNode child : n.children) {

      /* compute height of each subtree */
      long childHeight = height(child);

      /* use the larger one */
      highest = Math.max(highest, childHeight);
    }
    return highest + 1;
  }
  return 0;    
}
```

As for `levelOrder`, you can follow the same logic there. I'll leave it as an exercise for you.

---

Addressing this comment:

> Will you please guide me how to find a subtree from non binary tree?

Since this is an arbitrary tree, not a BST, we do not know anything about the order of the children, so we can't go hunting for specific values. Therefore, to find a subtree, we'll have to check every child.

```
/**
* haystack represents the tree we're looking inside
* needle is the tree we're looking for
*/
private boolean isSubTree(TNode haystack, TNode needle) {
  if (haystack == null && needle == null) {
    // Leaf
    return true;
  }
  if (haystack == null || needle == null) {
    // One is null, the other isn't
    return false;
  }
  if (haystack.value != needle.value) {
    // No match
    return false;
  }

  // We'll assume that order matters, and that all children need to match.
  if (haystack.children.size() != needle.children.size()) {
    return false;
  }

  // Iterate over all children and see if they match
  boolean result = true;
  for (int index = 0; index < haystack.children.size(); index++) {
    result = result && isSubTree(
      haystack.children.get(index),
      needle.children.get(index));
  }  
  return result;
}
```

To invoke it, iterate over all nodes in this.root (perhaps by using `levelOrder`) and call the above method, returning true if any one call returns true. It's a O(n*m) algorithm, where n is the number of nodes in the haystack and m is the number of nodes in the needle.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. But height is showing with one increment. I am trying to fix by myself.

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, @AliAhsan!

Comment: Will you please guide me how to find a subtree from non binary tree?

Comment: @AliAhsan: What kind of subtree is it? Is `b->c` a subtree of `a->b->c->d`? I.e., do all of the children need to match from a shared root, or is it just if the elements that intersect have the same parent/child structure?

Comment: The code is same and i have to implement the sub tree function. Above code will be used.

Comment: I have to implement the following function. public boolean isSubTree(Tree st){
        
      return false;
   }

Comment: I've added a sketch of the algorithm you could use to implement isSubTree to my answer.

Comment: Actually we cannot change the parameters of the function. We must have to use this. public boolean isSubTree(Tree st){ return false; } According to your answer you are taking two parameters of TNode class which we cannot use.

Comment: Yes, you have to use my algorithm within your function. I'm leaving that up to you. As I stated, `To invoke it, iterate over all nodes in this.root (perhaps by using levelOrder) and call the above method, returning true if any one call returns true.`

Comment: I am unable to understand. As my tree class uses root and size two data varriables only.

Comment: You have `this.root` and `st.root` available to you in the `isSubTree` method.

Comment: At this point, what you're after is a significantly different problem from the question you've asked above, so I would suggest the following: A) get a new, minimal snippet that you have to try to solve the `isSubTree` bit, B) be specific about what you want it to do and where your attempt is failing (with error messages, if applicable, and inputs and outputs) and C) put all of that in a new question titled "What is wrong with my isSubTree method?" tagged `java`, `algorithm`, `tree` and `data-structures`.